# How get value from array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [org_name] => name
            [field_name] => fullname
            [new_name] => Name
            [index] => 3
            [modified] => 2016-05-17 10:45:17
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [org_name] => reception_no
            [field_name] => reception_no
            [new_name] => Reception No.
            [index] => 1
            [modified] => 2016-05-17 10:45:17
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [org_name] => pno
            [field_name] => pno
            [new_name] => Personel No.
            [index] => 0
            [modified] => 2016-05-17 10:45:17
        )
```

and i want for example
where object has 'pno' get value of 'index' in this example for example '0'
is there possible to do that ?

Comment: Try this `echo $arr[0]->index`, This is an object array, so you need to use `->` for access the array. and use foreach loop for all.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to return the value of the 'index' property of the object that has the property 'pno'? What do you want to occur if more than one object has that property?

Comment: @oroboto yes exactly , but the key is unique

Comment: elaborate your question "where object has 'pno' get value of 'index' in this example for example '0' is there possible to do that " - paraphrase it to make it clear

Comment: `foreach ($array as $data) {
    if ($data->org_name == 'pno') {
        echo $data->index;
    }
}`

Comment: @FrayneKonok i need get dynamically because it may change in array maybe there is pno in 0 or 2

Comment: The o, 1, 2... is the pno?? Than just use `echo $arr[$pno]->index`

Comment: @FrayneKonok is it possible ?

Comment: what is $pno ? $pno='pno' ?

Comment: I am asking about the `pno`, I just saw it is inside the loop, So you need to loop and if any one gets the `pno` then print the index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112743/discussion-between-dude-and-frayne-konok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $items)
{
   if ($items->org_name=='pno')
     $index=$items->index;
 }
```

Comment: you need to break the loop at match, No need to loop through entire array after getting the result.

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible try this

```
var_dump($arr[0]->index);
```

**OR**

```
print_r($arr->index['0']);
```

Answer (score 1):

As i am asking you about the `pno`, I think it was the first index like 0,1,2..., But after some conversation this is clear that it is inside the sub array.

So you need a loop here and check for the `pno`, if matched then echo the index. Let your array is `$array`

```
foreach ($array as $key => $val){
    if($val->org_name == 'pno'){
        echo $index = $val->index;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_search

```
$key1 = array_search('pno', array_column($your_array, 'field_name'));


$key2 = array_search('pno', array_column($your_array, 'org_name'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_search since you may not know the index

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 0):

Tested with ur Array

```
$array = array(
        array('id'=>1,'org_name'=>'name','field_name'=>'fullname','new_name'=>'Name','index'=>3,'modified'=>'2016-05-17 10:45:17'),
        array('id'=>3,'org_name'=>'reception_no','field_name'=>'reception_no','new_name'=>'Reception No.','index'=>1,'modified'=>'2016-05-17 10:45:17'),
        array('id'=>4,'org_name'=>'pno','field_name'=>'pno','new_name'=>'Personel No.','index'=>0,'modified'=>'2016-05-17 10:45:17')
        );
```

This Code should do what u want

```
$index = '';    
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if($value['org_name']=='pno')
    {
        $index = $value['index'];
    }
}
print $index;
```

Script only Loops through ur Array and sets $index on the last found `pno` index value

U can check $index in an IF, if ist empty.